Power query: transform only one column into header and bring values from another column into corresponding columns
I may not describe well my question. I would like to only transform one column and make that column's values as new column header. And the cell value for these new columns will be based from another column.
I have a database like below:



Ref number
Task name
Task completed date




Ref1234
task1
02/12/2023


Ref1234
task2
03/05/2022


Ref1234
task3
02/11/2023


Ref1233
task1
03/05/2023


Ref1233
task2
02/02/2021


Ref1233
task3
03/10/2022



How can I use power query to change into this table:



Ref number
task1
task2
task3




Ref1234
02/12/2023
03/05/2022
02/11/2023


Ref1233
03/05/2023
02/02/2021
03/10/2022



I tried unpivot, transform, and pivot but none of them work properly. I have quite big database.
Many thanks!

I assume your original table is called "Table1", below code should work:
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  tasks = List.Distinct(Source[#"Task name"]),
  grouped = Table.Group(Source, {"Ref number"}, {"TaskInfos", each Record.FromList([#"Task completed date"], [#"Task name"])}),
  AddSubTable = Table.AddColumn(grouped, "SubTable", each Table.FromRecords({Record.AddField([TaskInfos], "Ref number", [Ref number])})),
  FilteredColumns = Table.SelectColumns(AddSubTable, {"SubTable"}),
  Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(FilteredColumns, "SubTable", {"Ref number"}&tasks, {"Ref number"}&tasks)
in
  Expanded

As horseyride suggested, I changed the last step to Table.ExpandTableColumn. it has better control over the order the columns, and makes the code cleaner.


It groups your original table be ref number, and create a sub table based on each group's task names and task completed dates.

So why not expand the tables as last step?

@horseyride, yes, that is much better!

Click select task name column .. transform ... pivot column ... values column:task completed [x] advanced options: do not aggregate

